# How to set the Control Visibilty of the Second Control depending on the Binding Value of the first

Tags: wpf, binding, wpf-controls, visibility

I have a Custom Wpf Control i.e. `combobox:WpfTwComboBox`. I want to set the visibility using a property called `DisableProviderSelector`.

The usual use of triggers is not helping. The scenario here is when the above control i.e. WindowsFormsHost is made visible or collapsed, I want the opposite to happen to the below custom control.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Height="25" Orientation="Horizontal"     
            Width="375" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <WindowsFormsHost Height="25" Width="375">
        <WindowsFormsHost.Style>
            <Style TargetType="WindowsFormsHost">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DisableProviderSelector}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DisableProviderSelector}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>     
            </Style>
        </WindowsFormsHost.Style>
        <commonControls:ProviderSelectorControl RequiredLevel="Save" ModifiedByUser="providerSelectorControl1_ModifiedByUser" x:Name="providerSelectorControl1"/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
    <combobox:WpfTwComboBox x:Name="PortalProviderSelector"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPortalProvider}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PortalProvidersCollection}" 
                            DisplayMemberPath="FullName" Width="350" Height="25"
                            RequiredLevelFlag="Save">
    </combobox:WpfTwComboBox>            
</StackPanel>
```

Can anyone please help me on how to set the visibility here?

Answer (score 1):

So `DisableProviderSelector` is a bool when set to True `WindowsFormsHost` needs to be `Collapsed` and `ComboBox` needs to be `Visible`. Reverse when bool is false.

So as far as the `ComboBox` is concerned if bool is True it's `Visible` and when False it's `Collapsed`. Thus just bind the `ComboBox` directly to the Property and use a `BooleantoVisibilityConverter`

xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<combobox:WpfTwComboBox x:Name="PortalProviderSelector"
                        Width="350"
                        Height="25"
                        DisplayMemberPath="FullName"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PortalProvidersCollection}"
                        RequiredLevelFlag="Save"
                        Visibility="{Binding DisableProviderSelector,
                                            Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                        SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPortalProvider}" />
```